# Android - Query contacts with phone number, return Name and Company, even if Company has not been specified

Tags: android, android-contacts

As stated in the title, I want to query all Contacts that have specified a phone number and return a cursor that contains only the display name and company name of the contact.  I would like only 1 row returned for each contact.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
Cursor contactsCur = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY},
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " >? AND " + Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " =? " ,
        new String[] {"0", ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
        null );
```

This will return 1 row for each Contact that has both a phone number and a company specified - it does not include contacts that have not specified a company.

I know why it does that - the `AND " + Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " =? "` bit of the query prevents any contact without a company from being returned.  The problem is that without the `AND` part, multiple rows for each contact is returned.

It appears this is because `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY` actually refers to `ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1` , which is a general use field.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi gnub,so what is the output you actually want?As far as I have understood do you want the contacts name even if it does not have a company name?

Comment: @Mukund yes.  I want the contact name and , if it exists, the company name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multiple queries for this